# number of samples generated in aggregate report are twice as compared to previous run

Tags: jmeter

M doing concurrency testing using JMeter with 100 concurrent users and ran the script and got fine results without any error but when next time I ran the same script for same number of users I observed that number of samples are doubled as compared to previous run and also the number of sessions are increased to 3000-4000.
please help me why is dis happenning.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to using the same .jtl results file, your newer results get appended to older ones. Delete or move results file somewhere and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi thanx for your reply but m using different .jtl file and running the script in non gui mode.Also help me about the number sessions.how the number of sessions established is related to the number of active threads or is the number of sessions established are related to number of hits.please provide your comments.

Comment: JMeter in non-GUI mode doesn't replace previous results file, results are appended and what you see in listeners is cumulative report for all recorded test runs. For the second bit: I believe [Active Threads Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener is what you're looking for. [http://jmeter-plugins.org/](JMeter Plugins) projects offers a variety of listeners which make test results analysis process faster and easier. You can also try out [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org/) - it is also very convenient